# two dimensional array to Update into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this array:

```
 Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015-07-20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 70
            [1] => 17
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 66
            [1] => 17
        )
)
```

Now I want Update to database like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2015-07-20 
            [2] => 2 
            [3] => 70 
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 66   
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2015-07-20 
            [2] => 5 
            [3] => 17 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 17  
        )
 )
```

Is it possible? Or qny other way to UPdate record from array?

I have foreach loop OUTPUT like this:-

```
UPDATE update_shopwise_stock SET shop_id =2 datetime =2015-07-20 item_id =2 item_id =5 before_sale_totitem_qty =70 before_sale_totitem_qty =17 after_sale_totitem_qty =4 after_sale_totitem_qty = restOfItem =66 restOfItem =17 note =NULL WHERE shop_id =2
```

But I Want to this:-

```
UPDATE update_shopwise_stock SET shop_id =2 datetime =2015-07-20 item_id =2 before_sale_totitem_qty =70 after_sale_totitem_qty =4 restOfItem =66 note =NULL WHERE shop_id =2

UPDATE update_shopwise_stock SET shop_id =2 datetime =2015-07-20 item_id =5 before_sale_totitem_qty =17 after_sale_totitem_qty = restOfItem =17 note =NULL WHERE shop_id =2
```

Any help?

Comment: MySQL UPDATE syntax needs a comma separated list of columns/values.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question you need transform data from first array to second array and after you can make this foreach?

If yes there is transform to array with default values from 0 index. Works for multiple versions so you can add index 3,5, etc. and it will works still.

```
$default = array();

$versions = array();
foreach($array as $key => $values){
    foreach($values as $version => $value){
        if($version === 0){
            $default[$key] = $value;
            continue;
        }
        if(!array_key_exists($version, $versions)){

        }
        $versions[$version][$key] = $value;
    }
}

$return  = array(
    0 => $default,
);
foreach($versions as $version => $versionData){
    $return[$version] = $versionData+$default;
}
```

If you need foreach to build your SQL query it is here to:

```
$columns = array(
    'shop_id', 'datetime', 'item_id', 'before_sale_totitem_qty', 'after_sale_totitem_qty', 'restOfItem'
);

foreach($return as $version => $data){
    $columnData = array();
    foreach($data as $columnIndex => $value){
        $columnData[] = sprintf('%s = %s', $columns[$columnIndex], $value);
    }
    $sql = sprintf('UPDATE update_shopwise_stock SET %s WHERE shop_id=%d', implode(', ', $columnData), $data[0]);
}
```

But my personal recommendation is not use sql like this, but use PDO for prepare statement and better security. For prepare statement is for loop here:

```
$columns = array(
    'shop_id', 'datetime', 'item_id', 'before_sale_totitem_qty', 'after_sale_totitem_qty', 'restOfItem'
);

foreach($return as $version => $data){
    $columnPrepare = array();
    $columnData = array();
    foreach($data as $columnIndex => $value){
        $columnName = $columns[$columnIndex];
        $columnPrepare[] = sprintf('%s = :%s', $columnName, $columnName);
        $columnData[$columnName] = $value;
    }
    $query = $db->prepare(sprintf("UPDATE update_shopwise_stock SET %s WHERE shop_id=:shop_id", implode(', ', $columnPrepare)));
    foreach($columnData as $column => $value){
        $query->bindParam(sprintf(':%s', $column), $value);
    }
    $query->execute();
}
```

**Everything is untested and can have some bugs, eventually performance issue. It is based on question issue and show only way how to solve this issue.**

Comment: No need to vast code I just use array_map that solved my prob, Thx to try to ans my question